# In the 2014 movie The Frame, what does the violin symbolise?

Tags: the-frame

Jamin Winans's 2014 movie *[The Frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frame_(film))* is a film loaded with symbolism and metaphor but the thing I keep coming back to is the violin.

> I suspect it represents faith as Alex appears to have lost his when his parents were murdered

But I could be wildly incorrect.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the film, it's labeled as Science Fiction, but I'd argue it more fantastical.

Comment: I'll update my tags. Sorry, new to this and learning as I go.

Comment: Hi there! I've taken the liberty to edit out the last part as your question is on-topic (and may have an answer from a director/writer etc), but the "hearing other people's opinion" isn't really what Stack Exchange sites are about. May I encourage to take the [tour] and browse the [help] to see how things work around here? :)

Comment: @DonTen: No worries on the tags. As a new person, you can't create new tags like that. Once you have a bit more rep, you will be able to.

Answer (score 3):

I spoke to my good friend [Kiowa Winans](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2026881/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr2) (producer of *The Frame*) via email. I'm sure she won't mind me sharing her response with a fellow fan.

> **Q.** [I'm] *getting hung up on the symbolism of the violin and what it represents. I can't decide if it's something to do with Alex's faith or the fact that he used to have joy in his life* [or something else entirely].
>
> **Kiowa:** *Jamin isn't too keen on revealing plot items because he doesn't want to mess with people's interpretations but... **I'd say you're on the right track with both here.***
>
> <sub><sup>*(Emphasis mine)*</sup></sub>

So the short answer is that it's been left [intentionally ambiguous](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmbiguousSituation) by the director, but it has elements that relate to both his childhood *and* his religious faith.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for your time and effort in this, it's greatly appreciated.